# How can I assemble and control two different hands on a watch face?

Tags: design

I want to make a device with two hands that rotate independently of each other, just like the hour and minute hands on a watch. I'm struggling to figure out how to actually design and implement this though.

Both hands should be able to rotate arbitrary amounts, either clockwise or counter clockwise, without concern for what the other hand is doing. I have a microcontroller with various I/O pins to send any necessary signals.

The two hands would sit at slightly different heights I assume, to prevent running into each other, but I don't know what to even search for to drive the two. Can you provide some suggestions?

Comment: You could use some stepper motor for accurate angular movement.

Comment: Can I get a stepper motor with multiple rotations on a single shaft?

Comment: The hour hand is mounted on a pipe; the minute hand on an axle that runs through the pipe. 

The pipe is attached to the "hour wheel", a gear that could be driven by a pinion on the hour stepper's shaft. 

The axle (aka "cannon pinion") could be directly driven by another stepper, or it could be geared too, so the steppers can be mounted side by side.

Comment: No.This detail is more a mechanical one than an electrical.How small is your application ?

Comment: About 4" x 4" or so.

Comment: For reference, this is how a center gear looks like https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/Tidens_naturlære_fig23.png/480px-Tidens_naturlære_fig23.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tandem stepper motors or synchros or servo motors; one with a [**hollow shaft**](https://www.google.com/search?q=hollow%20shaft%20stepper%20motor&espv=2&biw=1164&bih=874&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_vrT3vt_KAhXHYiYKHddZBGkQsAQIKA) to which one hand will be attached, and one with a solid shaft to which the other hand will be attached, the solid shaft rotating in the first shaft's hollow space, like this:

[image]

Comment: How to get the hollow one around the solid one? I sketched on my whiteboard a way to do this with a hollow tube and either a belt or a gear to attach it to the other stepper, is that the way you would suggest?

Comment: @samoz: No. "In tandem" means one behind the other. I've edited my answer to illustrate the concept.

Comment: Ahh the hollow shaft runs _through_ the entire stepper, got it! I thought it just referred to the end of the stepper motor being hollow. A picture really is worth 1000 words, thanks!